# TypeScript ES6 namespaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a Node.js project I recently converted to TypeScript from ECMAScript 6-compatible JavaScript. I am still not entirely familiar with how TypeScript and ES6 interact, especially in regards to namespaces and types.

I have a subfolder in my project called `sql` which, as it sounds, exports a number of functions to interact with the project's MySQL database. I would like to organize my DB model types in a `Sql.Models` namespace, so they can be referenced e.g. `Sql.Models.User`. I would like my models to be declared in one or more `.d.ts` files inside the `sql` folder, but I can't figure out how to properly organize this so that these types can be referenced elsewhere. I obviously cannot `require` or `import` a `.d.ts` file; that's not a valid TypeScript operation. How can I use the type `Sql.Models.User` declared in a `.d.ts` file in another ES6-compatible TypeScript module?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the type Sql.Models.User declared in a .d.ts file in another ES6-compatible TypeScript module?

The following very simple setup works.

```
root
  sql
    models.d.ts
  index.ts
  tsconfig.json
```

The `model.d.ts` file declares a namespace and a type. As the image demonstrates, the `index.ts` file can alias that namespace and/or access it directly.

[image]

The above is using TypeScript version 2.2.1.

Comment: When I set it up like this, I cannot access `Sql.Models` from another file that has a root-level namespace `Sql`. Perhaps I'm thinking too much in terms of the way C# works, where multiple files can participate in a namespace.

I'd like to have one class provide the `Sql` namespace and be the only file others in my project need to require. It will define a few common functions, such as `query`. But I would also like other namespaces that provide, e.g., models as described above, all being children of the `Sql` namespace.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you want to have one namespace called `Sql` and another child namespace called `Sql.Models`?

Comment: That's correct. I think I managed to work this out by having a `models.ts` file next to `sql.ts` that exports the model interfaces, then importing them in `sql.ts` and re-exporting them inside their proper namespace in that file (`import * as models from "./models"` and then later `export namespace Sql { export namespace Models { export type User = models.User; } }`. It's not a pretty as I'd like it, but it works and yields the end result I want.

Comment: It seems like you have answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a less-than-pretty fashion by using "aliased internal imports" which sound strange but really aren't. I export an alias to an internal symbol, which just happens to be a symbol imported from another file.

[image: source code]

I would have preferred something like how C# works, where I can define the namespace in two files and somehow alias one from another so that only one file needs to be referenced, but this doesn't seem possible with ECMAScript 6-compatible TypeScript.